# HTML 5 video tag not showing on website source

Tags: video, youtube, html5

whenever i view the page source of a website that plays HTML5 video, there is no < video > tag in it. here is a sample HTML5 video webpage: [link]youtube.com/watch?v=mzPxo7Y6JyA

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask questions—that's not encouraged.

Comment: it's just that my first post was not answered. i deleted it before posting another question. i was thinking that was valid. but thanks slhck

Comment: If you delete questions to re ask them, your account might be blocked from asking any further questions at some point. This is just a heads up.